# How to deploy GWT App to Google App Engine?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt-maven-plugin, gwt-maven-archetypes

I am using `gwt-maven-archetypes` and I have the problem that I can't recall how I can deploy my application to the Google App Engine.

It's been a while since I did this last time. I can remember that there is a command line tool that I have to use since the GWT Plugin for Eclipse does not work with the `gwt-maven-archetypes` or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Use a GAE Archetype and then use "Deploy to App Engine..." from the plugin menu; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4825543/2080575).

You might also be able to mark your current project as an App Engine project in Properties > Google > App Engine > check "Use App Engine" to be able to deploy with the plugin.